# Refreshing react page does not pass parent state to the child state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

When I try to load my component for the first time, the parent state is passed perfectly to the child. Every thing looks good. However, when i refresh my page, I just cannot see the state being passed into the child. I just see some static content from the child. Following is my parent:

```
render(){

    const {courses} = this.props;
    // debugger;
    let fn = (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
            courses: courses
        });
    };

    let childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, fn);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <h1>CoursesPage</h1>
                <p>This page adds and lists all the courses</p>
                <Link to="/courses/courseslist">
                    <Button color="primary">Course Listing</Button>
                </Link>
            </div>
            {childrenWithProps}
        </div>

    );
}
}

CoursesPage.propTypes = {
    courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    return {
        courses: state.courses
    };
}

//mapping all course actions to actions in the props
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(courseActions, dispatch)
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CoursesPage);
```

Also, this is my child component:

```
class CourseDetailsAndList extends React.Component {
constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            courses: this.props.courses
        };
    }
render(){
    const {courses} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Courses</h1>
            <CourseList courses={this.state.courses}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

CourseDetailsAndList.propTypes = {
    courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

When I refresh the page, I do not see the courses state passed in the child, just see a blank child. On the same lines, I see this warning in the console, which certainly looks one of the reason:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `courses` is marked as required in `CourseDetailsAndList`, but its value is `undefined`.
in CourseDetailsAndList (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router
in Provider
```

Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong i passing the state to the child component? And why the warning?

Comment: You've got `courses` commented out in `CoursesPage.propTypes`.

Are you sure you're passing in a valid value for `CoursesPage.courses`?

Comment: @Scott yes I am passing the right value. The button onclick event pulls the data correctly in the first instance. When i refresh the page, it just shows the child and not the data. That means the action to GET data is not triggering. But I am not understanding where I am going wrong. Do i need mapDispatchToProps in the child component as well?

Comment: `mapDispatchToProps` is a redux helper method, so whether you'd use that in this instance would be based on whether you're using redux in this app.

in the code you shared above, you've only included the `render` method of your `CoursesPage` component. can you share the whole component?

Comment: @Scott sure, I am editing my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of what you're trying to accomplish, using simplified versions of your components:

https://jsfiddle.net/79qk1r50/2/

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {parentProp} = this.props;
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {parentProp: parentProp});
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ParentComponent</h1>
        My parentProp is: {parentProp}
        {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {parentProp} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Child Component</h2>
        Received from parent: {parentProp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <ParentComponent parentProp={'foo'}>
    <ChildComponent />
    <ChildComponent />    
  </ParentComponent>,
  document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: hey Scott, this definitely works, except for i was using react-router to render child components instead of hardcoding them in the render function.